# I need help to change image with mouseover function

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I need help to change image with mouseover function

I only get one image and I need multiple images, I attach my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=f, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>JS practice Image Mouse Over</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- -->
  <div id="div"></div> 
  <img src="img/01.SanitariosC.png" alt="Sanitarios" id="sanitarios"> 
  <img src="img/02.GriferiasC.png" alt="Griferias" id="griferias">
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/* SANITARIOS*/ 
let image = document.getElementById('sanitarios'); 
function changeToLike() { 
  image.src="img/01.SanitariosE.png"; 
} 

function changeToDislike() { 
  image.src="img/01.SanitariosC.png"; 
}

image.addEventListener('mouseover', changeToLike); image.addEventListener('mouseout', changeToDislike);
```

```
/* GRIFERIAS*/ 
let image1 = document1.getElementById1('griferias'); 

function changeToLike1() { 
  image1.src="img/02.GriferiasE.png"; 
} 

function changeToDislike1() { 
  image1.src="img/02.GriferiasC.png"; 
} 

image1.addEventListener1('mouseover', changeToLike1); image1.addEventListener1('mouseout', changeToDislike1);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [mcve]. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: When adding code tio your question you should never use the comments section of your  question, intsead click on the edit button and add your code using the `{}` button, this will format your string of text that is code as code in question.

Answer (score 0):

## **Try this code**

```js
var image = document.getElementById("imageId");

image.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
  image.src = "https://planetcoms.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/happy-smiley.png"
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>mouse hover & change picture in JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/a5/e0/15a5e0513b6c4811b928b96d96d5ce29.png" width="175px" id="imageId">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to change the image's src is add listener to image or image div

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>mouse hover & change picture in JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="oldImg.png" class="oldImg">
</body>
</html>
```

Add the listener to image

```
let image = document.querySelector("oldImg");

image.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>{
  image.src = "newImg.png"
})
```